# Samsung Keyboard problem using commit content APi

Tags: android-softkeyboard

Im using Android Image Support, using IME (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/image-keyboard) but problem is when using Samsung Keyboard it returns null and using Google Keyboard it works perfectly. How can i support Samsung Keyboard using **Commit Content API**, which provides a universal way for IMEs to send images using soft keyboards. TIA.